# Record audio into mutil-small block each duration with getUserMedia

Tags: audio-recording, getusermedia

I think I should begin with an example of what I want:

1. User allow the web page to access mic, then start recording.
2. Every 3 seconds (for example) capture what the user say (maybe into an Blob).
3. Repeat until user want to stop.

I've found many example that use [AudioContext.createScriptProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createScriptProcessor) but it work by given a buffer size, I love to have similar thing but given a duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use [recorderjs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs), and use it in the below mentioned fashion:

```
    var rec = new Recorder(source);
    rec.record();
    var recInterval = setInterval(function(){
        rec.exportWAV(function(blob){
            rec.clear();
            // do something with blob...           
        });
    }, 3000); // 3000 - to get blob for every three seconds.
```

later on some button click, add `rec.stop()` to end .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :) BTW can you show me which lib can do similar thing but for video?

Comment: you can do similar steps with the RecordRTC library, https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC, but recording in chrome is going to be trickier as video and audio has to be recorded seperately